# как записать переменную в append()

Tags: jquery

если переменыу в виде

```
var vid1 = ('<div  class="vidd"><iframe  width="560" height="315" src="https://www.youtube.com/embed/PKRSCG7aIsM" frameborder="0" allow="accelerometer; autoplay; encrypted-media; gyroscope; picture-in-picture" allowfullscreen></iframe></div>');
var vid2 = ('<div  class="vidd"><iframe  width="560" height="315" src="https://www.youtube.com/embed/zAY0FjxsjZY" frameborder="0" allow="accelerometer; autoplay; encrypted-media; gyroscope; picture-in-picture" allowfullscreen></iframe></div>');
var vid3 = ('<div  class="vidd"><iframe  width="560" height="315" src="https://www.youtube.com/embed/meGsAvHRma0" frameborder="0" allow="accelerometer; autoplay; encrypted-media; gyroscope; picture-in-picture" allowfullscreen></iframe></div>');
var vid4 = ('<div  class="vidd"><iframe  width="560" height="315" src="https://www.youtube.com/embed/TzhbdV5iKgM" frameborder="0" allow="accelerometer; autoplay; encrypted-media; gyroscope; picture-in-picture" allowfullscreen></iframe></div>');
var vid5 = ('<div  class="vidd"><iframe  width="560" height="315" src="https://www.youtube.com/embed/TzhbdV5iKgM" frameborder="0" allow="accelerometer; autoplay; encrypted-media; gyroscope; picture-in-picture" allowfullscreen></iframe></div>');
var vid6 = ('<div  class="vidd"><iframe  width="560" height="315" src="https://www.youtube.com/embed/TzhbdV5iKgM" frameborder="0" allow="accelerometer; autoplay; encrypted-media; gyroscope; picture-in-picture" allowfullscreen></iframe></div>');
```

то как путем перебора их записать

```
jQuery('.mvid').append(?????????);
```

конструкция такая

```
 function video(num) {

[1,2,3,4,5,6].forEach(function(el) { 
if (el === num) { 
jQuery('.mvid').append(vid + el);
}

});
}
jQuery('.vid1').click(function() {video(1)});
jQuery('.vid2').click(function() {video(2)});
jQuery('.vid3').click(function() {video(3)});
jQuery('.vid4').click(function() {video(4)});
jQuery('.vid5').click(function() {video(5)});
jQuery('.vid6').click(function() {video(6)});
```

спасибо

Comment: у вас же всё в iframe одинаково кроме url  т.е если менять только `https://www.youtube.com/embed/KRSCG7aIsMP` т.е только вот это `KRSCG7aIsM` наверно так проще

Comment: не в это проблема, непойму как переменную записать. сам синтаксис в append()

Comment: значок доллара перед var vid1 = $('<div ....

Comment: дело в то что конструкция vid + el не работает как ее то записать

Comment: если записывать просто append(var1) выводит что надо, но это только одно....

Answer (score 0):

Почему-то мне кажется, что автор пытается реализовать некий "видео-плеер с выбором серий", если оно так и есть, то почему бы не переделать "механику"?

Предлагаю следующий вариант, который использует массив с ссылками на "серии".
Такой вариант проще и можно "расширить функционал".

```js
// Массив с ссылками на видео
let videoArr = [
  'https://www.youtube.com/embed/PKRSCG7aIsM',
  'https://www.youtube.com/embed/zAY0FjxsjZY',
  'https://www.youtube.com/embed/meGsAvHRma0',
  'https://www.youtube.com/embed/TzhbdV5iKgM',
  'https://www.youtube.com/embed/TzhbdV5iKgM',
  'https://www.youtube.com/embed/TzhbdV5iKgM'
];

// При загрузке страницы - грузим видосы
function ReadyVideo() {
  $.each(videoArr, function(i){
    // Создаём список видео
    $('.video-block .list').append('<div class="item" data-videolink="'+videoArr[i]+'">'+(i+1)+'</div>');
    if(i==0) {
      // Первому вешаем класс active
      $('.video-block').find('.list .item').addClass('active');
      // И "вставляем" ссылку в фрейм
      $('.video-block').find('.frame iframe').attr('src', videoArr[i]);
    }
  });
}
ReadyVideo();

// Ну и переключение "серий"
$('.video-block .list').on('click', '.item', function(){
  // "отключим" переключение активной "серии"
  if(!$(this).hasClass('active')) {
    // Определяем ссылку, которую храним в "кнопке" при загрузке страницы
    let href = $(this).data('videolink');
    // Ищем активную "серию" и удаляем с неё класс active
    $('.video-block .list').find('.item.active').removeClass('active');
    // Ну и выбранной "серии" вешаем класс active
    $(this).addClass('active');
    // А дальше обновляем ссылку в самом фрейме
    $('.video-block .frame iframe').attr('src', href);
  }
});
```

```css
.video-block {
  display: block;
  width: 300px;
  height: 270px;
}

.video-block .list {
  display: block;
  width: 100%;
  height: 20px;
  overflow: auto hidden;
}

.video-block .list .item {
  display: inline-block;
  float: left;
  color: #fff;
  min-width: 20px;
  height: 20px;
  padding: 0 3px;
  background: gray;
  text-align: center;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  cursor: pointer;
}

.video-block .list .item:not(:last-child) {
  margin-right: 3px;
}

.video-block .list .item.active {
  background: black;
  color: white;
}

.video-block .frame {
  display: block;
  width: 100%;
  height: 250px;
}

.video-block .frame {
  display: block;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="video-block">
  <div class="list"></div>
  <div class="frame">
    <iframe src=""></iframe>
  </div>
</div>
```

Если мой ответ "ушёл" от темы автора, то переформулируйте вопрос.. Ну или отпишитесь в комменты.